# Web Development, Domain and Site Hosting

Tags: mysql, web, dns, hosting

I'm not 100% sure if I'm on the correct section but i'll transfer the post once I know where it's supposed to be but I am looking for advice regarding web development, setting up a domain and hosting it.

I'm currently working on a personal project using [Cloud9](https://c9.io/). Which is an online development environment where I can develop and host. The reason why I chose this is because it has MySQL usability as I retrieve and store data on the project I am working on.

I am now at the point where I want to get a domain and host a site to transfer my project over to a live website with my own domain which also has SQL/MySQL usability.

Any advice or where would be the best place to look up on methods of pursuing this?

Edit: I develop using PHP and JavaScript with MySQL

Answer (score 0):

To start I would suggest [heroku](https://www.heroku.com/), they have a free option and some nice [guides](https://devcenter.heroku.com/start), depending on which server side language you use . This way you can get used to hosting some apps and doing deployments, seeing logs etc.

The database doesn't have to be on the same hosting necessarily, you can use [mongolab](https://mlab.com/) for example.

For domain names it's a different thing,  you will have to use the likes of godaddy

Comment: Appreciate the reply. I haven't had a chance to have a good look through heroku yet but I think what you're saying is already what I have been doing. Cloud9 is a cloud based development environment/workspace. It hosts my project and I develop using their online IDE. What I am looking for is getting my own domain and hosting it. Transferring files/code over from Cloud9 to my domain and using a database along with it.

Comment: I see. One good option would be hosting it on [AWS](https://aws.amazon.com/websites/), they have a free year (with some limitations for example with storage size and computing power but for starting out is definitely more than enough), and you have several database options including MySQL which you are already familiar with. The learning curve might be more steep but it's definitely valuable to be familiar with AWS in the job market anyways. Heroku as I mentioned before would be also a valid choice and I heard good things about [DigitalOcean](https://www.digitalocean.com).

Answer (score 0):

Why not setup your own VPS (Virtual Private Server)? There are many providers..

Answer (score 0):

Design the software application with portability and avoid vendor lock-in to cloud services. For file transfer, there are FTP/FXP, zip/gzip, & version control standards like Git, CVS, SVN, etc. Use phpMyAdmin for the database export & import process to change web hosts. Otherwise, build a staging subdomain or a local development environment with copies of the original web app & use those to transfer files+DB to a new host for production.